# .Net Standard HttpClient lock up issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-standard

I wrote a .Net Standard Class Library that my WPF application is calling into.
I have a login method that I am calling to authenticate with my web api that I know works.

**EDIT - I literally cannot explain it and honestly I don't care to know why. If you wrap the whole thing in a try catch statement, it executes perfectly.... It never hits the catch statement either.**

If you step debug my code you will hit the line

> var result = await ...
>   After it hits this line it never continues, I don't see any exceptions, and nothing happens.

Here is my login code:

```
//Login
        using (_webClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<String,String>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "xxx"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "xxx")});

            var returnData = new LoginModel();
            var result = await _webClient.PostAsync(SSIUtils.TokenUrl, body);

            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetLoginModel>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            if (response.userName == null)
            {
                //Login failed
                returnData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetLoginErrorModel>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                //Login worked
                User.isAuthenticated = true;

                returnData = response;
            }


            return returnData;
        }
```

---

### Solution

```
using (_webClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<String,String>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "xxx"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "xxx")});

                var returnData = new LoginModel();
                var result = await _webClient.PostAsync(SSIUtils.TokenUrl, body);

                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetLoginModel>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                if (response.userName == null)
                {
                    //Login failed
                    returnData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetLoginErrorModel>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
                else
                {
                    //Login worked
                    User.isAuthenticated = true;


                    //We need to store this information
                    returnData = response;
                }


                return returnData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/